# Number of combinations for specific problem

Tags: statistics, stochastic-calculus

I'm currently programming a small script and have a statistical problem:
I have 24 sequences, consisting of 4 different characters and a length of 8 characters.
It is necessary to group the sequences to 8 sequences per group.

To make it more clear, here are two example groups:

```
Example 1: CAAGTCGT      Example 2: CAAGTCGT
           GTCTCATC                 GTCTCATC
           ACGTCGTT                 ACGTCGTT
           GTCCTGTT                 GTCCTGTT
           AGAAGCCT                 AGAAGCCT
           GAAGATCC                 GATGATCC
           TCGGATTC                 TCGGATTC
           CGGAGTAT                 CGGAGTAT
```

Eight sequences are in one group and I'm searching the number of combinations of these groups when:

1. Reading the sequences from top to bottom: From the first to the sixth position (left to right), every character should exist at least once (ACGT) on every position. In example 1, position 3 has no T, so this would not be a match (You don't have to care about this, because these groups are filtered in my script). However, example 2 has a T on position 3. This would match. In both examples, position 8 has neither an A or an G but because position 8 does not matter, it is fine.
2. The order doesn't matter. In example 1: If I would change the positions of sequence 1 and 4, this would be the same result. To reduce the computational load I already filtered these groups in my script. If I would replace just one sequence with one of the remaining (I displayed 8 but there are 16 others) sequences, this would be a new group which would count.

Again, I need the number of combinations while a group fulfils the above-mentioned criteria.

I hope I could express my problem in a proper way. If not, please do not hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: To summarize: a "good" collections is a list of eight strings, each string made from the same $4$ letters and each string has length $8$, and which has the property that each of the $4$ letters appears at least once in each of the first six slots, no conditions at all on the last two.  You want to count the good collections.  Yes?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it is necessary to have a good collection only once (as mentioned in condition 2). A different order of the same strings would be the same good collection.

Comment: What is the significance of the $24$ at the start?  Must all the strings come from those $24$?

Comment: Yes, I have exactly 24 strings. These are the base for building the combinations.

Comment: Ah, that's very different.  I expect the answer will depend heavily on those $24$.  (for example, if there are only three with $A$ in the first slot then you need one of each in each collection). I think you need to include them in the question.

Comment: @Alex they're similar but not identical.